# Vue.js how to add active class if index is 0

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

this is my code

```html
<li v-for="(data, index) in datas" :key="data.id" class="nav-item">
  <a :href="#" :class="'nav-link '+ { 'active' : index === 0 }"  data-toggle="tab">
    {{data.name}}
  </a>
</li>
```

but output only showing like this

```html
<a href="#" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link [object Object]">test</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add static class with dynamic class bindings by taking array of classes instead of concatenating by '+' operator.

```
<li v-for="(data, index) in datas" :key="data.id" class="nav-item">
  <a :href="#" :class="[nav-link,{ 'active' : index === 0 }]"  data-toggle="tab">
    {{data.name}}
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should do it as follows by separating the bound class from the not bound one :

```html
<a :href="#" class="nav-link" :class="{ 'active' : index === 0 }"  data-toggle="tab">
  {{data.name}}
</a>
```